# Auto complete search from multiple collections

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using nodejs, mongodb and angular, and want to build an autocomplete search like Facebook. when typing a keyword, it needs to search groups, users, pages etc.

For example, I have two collections: `users` and `companies`. They both have a `name` field. When someone type a keyword in the search bar, I will provide suggestions containing both the users and companies that have the entered text.  Using stuff like `User.find(name:"typed name")` and `Company.find("name:"typed name")`. The part I'm stuck on is how to suggest names from both collections, yet have the results look like it's from a single collection.

How can I combine the results from multiple collections into a single result collection?

Comment: This question is quite broad.  Is there a specific step in the "query from multiple collections" that you are not sure about?  Examples of code, such as getting stuff from a single collection could improve your question.

Comment: for examle I have two collections : users and companies , they both have  a name field  : when somene is searching by typing a keyword in the search bar I will suggest him the users and companies that having the entered name : User.find(name:"typed name")  and Company.find("name:"typed name") , the hard part for me is to suggest names from the two collections , it's like looking in both collections at the same time

Comment: I've edited your question to include the details you mention in your comment.  Your question is still missing some details.  For example, are you stuck combining your collections at the server/API layer?  Or just within the angular layer?  Any existing code for how you handle collections would also be helpful.